# Splitting Multiple Ranges from a Single Range in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, split, array-formulas

I am building a scheduling tool for my company. The structure of my Google Sheets document is a summary page with the entire schedule laid out for each employee in each department. Then, each employee gets their own sheet. In each employee sheets I have a section for Sunday, Monday, and Tuesday (the days each employee works). In each section by day I have a column indicating the hours they are on the clock, and then a column for each department. I have placed a checkbox into each cell and can activate the check box to indicate that this employee will be working in that department at that corresponding time. However, there are times when an employee is in a department more than once per day, meaning that the column with the checkboxes has, for example, checks in the cells corresponding to 7am-10am and 2pm-5pm, with unchecked boxes in the cells corresponding to 11am-1pm.

[image: Example of a single Day]

I have query functions that can pull the start and end times in that department if the employee is only in that department once per day. The output, after some concatenation, is something like "7AM-2PM".

```
=QUERY(A4:C17, "Select MIN(A) where (C=TRUE)")
```

---

```
=QUERY(A4:C17, "Select MAX(A) where (C=TRUE)")
```

However, I cannot think of a way to discriminate multiple start and end times. Using the above example, I'd like my output to be "7AM-10AM" and "2PM-5PM". These can be in separate cells or the same cell, doesn't make a difference to me. There can also be formulas in several cells if a subsequent formula needs to operate off a previous one.

I hope this makes sense in the way I have described it. I have been struggling for weeks trying to come up with something and am running out of time. Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, 
 TEXT(FILTER($A4:$A17, IF((B4:B17=TRUE)*({FALSE; B4:B16}=FALSE), 1, )=1), "hh:mm\ - ")&
 TEXT(FILTER($A4:$A17, IF((B4:B17=TRUE)*({B5:B17; FALSE}=FALSE), 1, )=1), "hh:mm"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Absolutely awesome! Thank you so much for this solution and for the speed in answering. Now to dissect and learn what each part of this formula does exactly.